# Grails, property names in embedded object in domain class causing problems

Tags: grails, grails-orm

I'm using grails 2.3.4 and I have a domain class that embeds an object. The embedded object has a property called 'version' and it seems that this is conflicting with the 'version'-field automatically added to the database-table by GORM. The result is that the 'version'-field belonging to my embedded object isn't created in the database and as a consequence my application doesn't work properly.

My code looks like this:

```
class Thing {
  String someText
  EmbeddedThing embeddedThing
  Date someDate

  static embedded = ['embeddedThing']

  static constraints = {
    embeddedThing(unique: true)
  }
}

class EmbeddedThing {
  String textOfSomeSort
  String version
  String textOfSomeOtherSort
}
```

You might think that a quick fix is to rename the 'version'-property of the embedded object but the class belongs to an included sub-project (i.e. a JAR-file) that I'm not allowed to touch since other projects use it. So the solution needs to be done completely within my domain class, or at least in a manner that doesn't change the class of the embedded object.

Comment: Do you need versioning on this domain class that comes with Grails? If not have you tried disabling it?

Comment: Disabling optimistic locking is unfortunately an option. And disabling it didn't work either.

Comment: Then due to the fact you are embedding this other class in your domain class there will be a conflict between it's property of version and the version used by the optimistic locking. Put simply, it won't work. Sorry.

Comment: I was afraid that would be the answer. I'll have to talk to the people responsible for the EmbeddedThing class and see if they'll let me change the name of the 'version'-property then. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually found a solution to this problem by using a Hibernate UserType to represent the EmbeddedThing-class.
My code now looks like this and works perfectly:

Thing.groovy:

```
import EmbeddedThingUserType

class Thing {
  String someText
  EmbeddedThing embeddedThing
  Date someDate

  static embedded = ['embeddedThing']

  static mapping = {
    version false
    embeddedThing type: EmbeddedThingUserType, {
      column name: "embedded_thing_text"
      column name: "embedded_thing_version"
      column name: "embedded_thing_other_text"
    }
  }

  static constraints = {
    embeddedThing(unique: true)
  }
}
```

EmbeddedThing.groovy:

```
class EmbeddedThing {
  String textOfSomeSort
  String version
  String textOfSomeOtherSort
}
```

EmbeddedThingUserType.groovy:

```
class EmbeddedThingUserType implements UserType {
  int[] sqlTypes() {
    return [StringType.INSTANCE.sqlType(),
        StringType.INSTANCE.sqlType(),
        StringType.INSTANCE.sqlType()]
  }

  Class returnedClass() {
    return EmbeddedThing
  }

  public Object nullSafeGet(ResultSet resultSet, String[] names, Object owner)
      throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (resultSet && names) {
      return new EmbeddedThing(
          textOfSomeSort: resultSet?.getString(names[0] ?: '_missing_textOfSomeSort_'),
          version: resultSet?.getString(names[1] ?: '_missing_version_'),
          textOfSomeOtherSort: resultSet?.getString(names[2] ?: '_missing_textOfSomeOtherSort_'))
    } else {
      return null
    }
  }

  public void nullSafeSet(PreparedStatement preparedStatement, Object value, int index)
      throws HibernateException, SQLException {
    if (value != null) {
      preparedStatement.setString(index, value?.textOfSomeSort)
      preparedStatement.setString(index + 1, value?.version)
      preparedStatement.setString(index + 2, value?.textOfSomeOtherSort)
    } else {
      preparedStatement.setString(index, '_missing_textOfSomeSort_')
      preparedStatement.setString(index + 1, '_missing_version_')
      preparedStatement.setString(index + 2, '_missing_textOfSomeOtherSort_')
    }
  }

  @Override
  public boolean isMutable() {
    return false
  }

  @Override
  public boolean equals(Object x, Object y) throws HibernateException {
    return x.equals(y)
  }

  @Override
  public int hashCode(Object x) throws HibernateException {
    assert (x != null)
    return x.hashCode()
  }

  @Override
  public Object deepCopy(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    return value
  }

  @Override
  public Object replace(Object original, Object target, Object owner)
      throws HibernateException {
    return original
  }

  @Override
  public Serializable disassemble(Object value) throws HibernateException {
    return (Serializable) value
  }

  @Override
  public Object assemble(Serializable cached, Object owner)
      throws HibernateException {
    return cached
  }
}
```

Config.groovy:

```
grails.gorm.default.mapping = {
    'user-type'( type: EmbeddedThingUserType, class: EmbeddedThing)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**version** is a special column name, you should rename your **version** field within your EmbeddedThin class

Comment: That was my first impulse but as I mentioned the EmbeddedThing class belongs to a sub-project that I'm not allowed to make changes to.

Answer (score -1):

Please try `version false` in your 'static mapping', for the 'EmbeddedThing' class.

Comment: As stated in the question modifications to EmbeddedThing can not be made.